# Puzzled with Java8 Stream performance

Tags: java, performance, lambda, java-8, performance-testing

I can't understand why iterating multiple time over a same array with Stream api
result in such a performance!

see the code below.

```
public class WhyIsDifferent {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] values = getArray();
    Iterate(values, 598, 600); // 70 ms
    Iterate(values, 200, 202); // 0 ms
    Iterate(values, 700, 702); // 0 ms
    Iterate(values, 300, 310); // 1 ms
}

public static void Iterate(int[] values, int from, int to) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    IntStream.of(values).filter(i -> i < to && i > from)
    .forEach(i -> 
        System.out.println(i) // do a something
    );
    System.out.println("Time:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
}

public static int[] getArray() {
    int[] values = new int[1000];
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        values[i] = i;
    }
    return values;
}
}
```

for sure JVM optimizes the code but i don't know how this happening?? It is amazing!
do you have any clue why this happening?

--

I'm testing on Ubuntu 14.04/ / Oracle jdk / intel cpu.

Comment: This is the [JIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) doing its job, my friend.

Comment: What @LuiggiMendoza says; and what is more you hit a "sweet spot", since by default the Oracle JVM, at least, will optimize after 1000 executions of the same code block.

Comment: I know but how?? how can JIT figure the filter part ?? It's weird!

Comment: That's JVM implementation dependent. And you should worry about it, just be grateful with JVM implementors.

Comment: One explanation of it is that a lambda is nothing but a "call site"; in your case, given the simplicity of your lambda, the JVM will certainly have inlined it altogether. Search on YouTube for "lambda peek under the hood" and watch the video: it is immensely instructive. In fact, the majority of the cost of the first iteration is probably due to the initial linkage!

Comment: In your case it’s very simple: there is only one existing `Predicate` implementation in the entire runtime. In more sophisticated use cases, it’s the built-in self profiler which will detect, which code path is actually executed (and worth optimizing).

Comment: This has nothing to do with lambdas.  The first invocation of Iterate will always be slower; this is how VMs work (interpret for a while, then do some compilation, etc.)  You need to measure more carefully.  Try using something like JMH.

Comment: initially I blamed the first invocation of iterate method; however after inlining all codes in the main method nothing have changed. seems as user @Marko Topolink stated bootstraping lambda takes time! I will measure the code with JMH to find exactly whats going on, Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not the JIT compiler. Most of those 70 milliseconds are spent on the initialization of the whole lambda subsystem (the entry point to that logic is probably the `LambdaMetaFactory` class) and a good bit is also spent on the lambda bootstrap call (the *linkage* phase, as mentioned by user fge). Check out this method, the same as yours but with all the steps separately measured (and I use `nanoTime`):

```
public static void Iterate(int[] values, int from, int to) {
  long start = System.nanoTime();
  final IntPredicate predicate = i -> i < to && i > from;
  System.out.println("Predicate lambda creation time:" + NANOSECONDS.toMillis(System.nanoTime() - start));
  start = System.nanoTime();
  final IntConsumer action = System.out::println;
  System.out.println("Action lambda creation time:" + NANOSECONDS.toMillis(System.nanoTime() - start));
  start = System.nanoTime();
  final IntStream stream = IntStream.of(values).filter(predicate);
  System.out.println("Stream creation time:" + NANOSECONDS.toMillis(System.nanoTime() - start));
  start = System.nanoTime();
  stream.forEach(action);
  System.out.println("Stream consumption time:" + NANOSECONDS.toMillis(System.nanoTime() - start));
}
```

This is what was printed on my machine:

```
Predicate lambda creation time:53
Action lambda creation time:2
Stream creation time:2
599
Stream consumption time:1
Predicate lambda creation time:0
Action lambda creation time:0
Stream creation time:0
201
... all timings zero from here on...
```

You can see that the entire overhead of the first call is in the lambda creation part (which, on the first run only, includes general initialization and linkage) and stream creation also takes some time. Actual stream consumption takes zero time in all cases.

This effect is definitely something to keep on your mind with the current version of HotSpot: lambda bootstrap is an expensive thing.

Final note: if you reorder the lambda creation statements, you'll see that the majority of time stays with the *first* lambda to be created. That shows us that it is actually only the first overall creation of a lambda which bears most of the initialization cost.

Comment: Even calling the method with different arrays result the same performance?? What is lambda bootstrap? do you have any reference to study about?

Comment: Check out my new edit, I have split out all the creation steps (two lambdas and the stream). Now stream consumption (`forEach` call) takes no time even on the first run. The array itself is irrelevant here --- unless you make it *really* big.

Comment: About reading material, I recommend the javadoc of [`LambdaMetaFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.html) as a great starting point.

Comment: "lambda bootstrap is an expensive thing" that's relative; it is still fast enough. It is all the faster in Java that call sites don't change that much. Unlike dynamic languages implemented over the JVM, argument types will not change from one call to the other (unlike in Scala, for instance).

Comment: @fge "Fast enough", if anything, is relative :) When I said "expensive", I meant that it could easily dwarf the actual time to execute the stream logic. BTW I'm surprised at what you say about Scala since it is a statically-typed language. How can argument types change for a specific call site? You mean different subtypes can be involved across calls? But there it's no different from Java.

Comment: Actually, your numbers disprove your statement. If the lambda bootstrap was expensive, the action lambda creation and the predicate lambda creation time took the same time. However, the first one took far longer as it’s the ordinary class loading (of the `LambdaMetaFactory` and it’s required classes) that is expensive, not the bootstrapping itself. Even the second one requires loading of `IntPredicate`. By the way, the question was not “why is the first execution slower” but “why is the subsequent execution so fast”. And in this regard you can’t dismiss the effect of JIT/HotSpot optimization.

Comment: @Holger Look at my "final note" which covers your first complaint. As for "why subsequent execution is so fast", it's rooted in mistaken thinking by OP: he should definitely consider spending 70 ms on 1000 simple operations extremely slow, as opposed to spending less than 1 ms exceptionally fast. Furthermore, I explain exactly why the JIT is irrelevant: there is no difference in observed timings when array size is set to zero. You are right about one point, though: I should have aditionally split class initialization time from lambda bootstrap.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: I don’t know whether I overlooked the final words or whether they weren’t there when I started writing my first comment. In either case, the version we have now is an improvement that deserves +1 and the questioner has no reason for hesitating to accept.

Comment: Dear Holger for your clarification I have some reason for hesitation. I should thank MarkoTopolnik for his great answer; the reason is i'm trying to  measure the performance with JMH as @Brian Goetz commented. then i can be sure about the answer. That's it. I'm very conservative with micro benchmarking :)

Comment: @MortezaAdi What JMH shows you will have nothing to do with your question here, which is why the first run was so slow. It will just show you the eventual performance of the stream.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik actually i was interested on how fast subsequent call is! not the slowness of the first call.your answer is absolutely helpful and the only acceptable answer so far to me; however let my research go on for another day :) thanks.

Comment: @MortezaAdi Don't think I'm putting any pressure on your accepting my answer. I'm just telling you where your research is going to take you. If you leave that `println` statement in there, then it's going to be the bottleneck; if you put in something very lightweight, then you may see some overhead from the stream.

Comment: I was researching on how JIT optimizing my code however i couldn't find any significant optimization here. the operation by itself is fast enough however as you said the initializing lambda takes time so i was mistakenly though JIT is doing something here. @MarkoTopolnik thanks a lot.